# Resign iOS App (ipa) for distribution

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, code-signing

I've successfully resigned my app. However there are still some open questions. These are the steps i did to resign the app:

1. I downloaded the appropriate provision profile from the apple member center.
2. I unzipped the ipa file: `unzip {AppName}.ipa`
3. Removed the old signature: `rm -rf Payload/{AppName}.app/_CodeSignature/`
4. Copied the new provisioning profile into the App: 
   `cp new.mobileprovision Payload/{AppName}.app/embedded.mobileprovision`
5. Resign the App: `codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: {CertificateName}" --entitlements Entitlements.plist Payload/{AppName}.app/`
6. Repack the App: `zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload`

I've looked up the `{CertificateName}` from the my Keychain under *My Certificates*. To get the `entitlements.plist` i used the following command:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :entitlements.plist Payload/{AppName}.app/
```

Now the open questions are:

Can i use this to resign an app and upload it to the app store? Is there anyone who actually did it this way successfully?

I have another folder besides Payload which is called Symbols. I suspect that this was added when the ipa was created for the app store. Do i need to repack it this way then: `zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload Symbols` to ensure that the Symbols are also within the app?

Within the Entitlements there is a part `keychain-access-groups`. Is this only relevant if i would use the keychain? Can i use the following value for it: `{Prefix}.*` or should it be more explicit?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, does the most of work for you when you upload your app [FastLane](https://fastlane.tools/)

Comment: Looks promising but doesn't answers any of my questions :/